# Rails transactions within transactions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

What happens when you have transactions with transactions

```
def a
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # stuff
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  a
  # more stuff
end
```

What happens if the inner transaction succeeds but the outer fails and vice versa? What happens when both succeed or fail?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `transaction` calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent transaction.

The behaviour is well described in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#label-Nested+transactions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested transaction in rails.But you have to focus on the rollbacking part in case of nested transaction. Check [nested-transations-in-rails](http://geekdirt.com/blog/nested-transations-in-rails/)  .

Comment: If you link to your own blog or something like that, you need to disclose that. A simple *"my"* is sufficient. Also, this does look a bit thin. Can you give a concrete example to go with that suggestion?